# Show system time upto minute on UWP UI

Tags: java, c#, uwp, timer

I want to show current Time on upto minute only in UWP. Time needs to be sync with system time so that system time and App time will show exact time upto minute .

I am using timer for this. Initial interval is based in current time.

```
private const string TIME_FORMAT = "hh:mm";

        private static int TIMER_INTERVAL_ONE_MINUTE = 60 * 1000;
        private static Timer countdownTimer;
        private static DateTime liveDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        private static bool isTimerRunning = false;
        static ViewModel()
        {
            countdownTimer = new Timer();
            countdownTimer.Elapsed += CountdownTimer_Elapsed;
            countdownTimer.Interval = TIMER_INTERVAL_ONE_MINUTE - DateTime.Now.Second;
            countdownTimer.Start();
            isTimerRunning = true;
        }

private static void CountdownTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            ApplicationDispatcher.RunOnUIThread(() =>
            {
                liveDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                countdownTimer.Interval = TIMER_INTERVAL_ONE_MINUTE;
            });
        }
```

But sometimes my UI is not in sync with System because statements needs some times to execute also which cases initial to set incorrectly with small fraction.
I don't want to run my timer too frequently.

How can I show time upto minute uwith sync System time.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

From your code, you are only assigning variables, which does not need to be done with `Thread`.

In UWP, the way to get the current time is through `DateTime.Now`. If you want to save the current time as a variable and keep it updated, you need a timer.

We recommend using `DispatcherTimer` in UWP app, it is a timer running on the UI thread, which can be written like this:

```cs
private DispatcherTimer _timer;
private static DateTime liveDateTime = DateTime.Now;
public ViewModel()
{
    _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    _timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    _timer.Start();
    // other code ...
}

private void Timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    liveDateTime = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Since it is not known when to start the timer, using one minute as the timing interval may cause delay. It is recommended to shorten the timer interval to 10 seconds or less.

Best regards.

Comment: I am aware of this. I want to run my timer on a interval of 1 minute otherwise it will be waste of resources if i ran the timer on every second.

Comment: I understand what you think, but unless you start counting at 0 seconds, a one-minute interval timer is bound to cause delay. In fact, if you only display the time and do nothing else, the impact on system resources will be minimal